# Add access point to wireless network

Tags: ieee-802.11, mesh

I've got an existing wireless network with two access points on it:

- A [TP-Link Archer C2600](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-c2600/) on 2.4GHz (802.11b/g/n mixed) and 5GHz (802.11a/n/ac mixed), with WPA/WPA2-Personal security;
- A [UniFi AP-AC-LR device](https://www.ui.com/unifi/unifi-ap-ac-lr/), extending the network through a powerline ethernet adapter.  I set the SSID and password the same as the TP-Link device.

Most devices seem to like this setup, they switch between the two networks according to which one has better signal for the device location.

I would like to add an outdoor access point similar to the [UniFi Mesh Access point, UAP-AC-M-US](https://store.ui.com/collections/unifi-network-access-points/products/unifi-ac-mesh-ap), but I'm confused by the "Mesh" terminology in its description.  Is this device meant to be used in a different kind of network setup than I have here?  Or does "Mesh" here just loosely mean "co-existing with other devices"?

Thanks for any insight you can offer, or corrections of any misunderstandings I might have.

Comment: This question, asked 8 months ago and having two very helpful answers, has just been closed today as "off topic."  There aren't even any comments explaining what's off-topic about it, what gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mesh ap's are able to use a wireless backhaul, without cable's, ap-mode or client-mode.  They will form a wireless backhaul mesh with other ap's that support mesh-mode, if configured correctly.
Technicaly a 'mesh' access point is an access point that support's [802.11s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11s)
 technology.

sometimes "mesh" is a marketing term for 'access point supports assisted wifi roaming'.  this means that the the ap's will optimize the client roaming experience.  eg active steering them to a better ap.  If you wish to use this technology, all ap's need to support this to help with the steering.  Technicaly this is called [802.11r](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11r-2008)

the [datasheet](https://dl.ubnt.com/datasheets/unifi/UniFi_AC_Mesh_DS.pdf) of the uap-ac-m-us does not show 802.11s, only 802.11r.  This is he same for the UniFi AP-AC-LR.

So the unifi ap's will help each other with roaming and distributing the clients across ap's.  The tp-link will also play along but without assisted roaming.
I expect your wifi experience to be the same or better then before.

note: I have never used t-link or unifi devices, but have setup campus wlan's with other wit similar technology.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.  So Mesh/802.11s sounds a bit more like using WiFi extenders, which is not what I'm looking for.  I'll plan to buy and install the UAP-AC-M-US and hook it up basically the same way I've done the AP-AC-LR, I'll report back here with the results.

Comment: Ubiquiti [doesn't really use mesh networking](https://community.ui.com/questions/UniFi-mesh-questions/39d520f3-0f74-4d1e-8d5d-c178aff1b954#answer/8ee6943a-7b75-4f9b-9fc7-1c76441595f7). Instead, the UniFi Network Controller configures a set of daisy-chain links with a static topology and then reconfigures the network if a node fails.

Answer (score 2):

"Mesh networking" is more of a marketing term; it [does not imply interoperability between vendors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_mesh_network#Routing_protocols). Unfortunately, even the 802.11s mesh networking standard doesn't guarantee interoperability as vendors add proprietary extensions. [Wi-Fi.org introduced "Easymesh"](https://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-easymesh) to address interoperability.

[For example](https://support.google.com/googlenest/thread/41677858?hl=en&msgid=41725347), "Google / Nest WiFi uses the standard 802.11s protocol to implement its core mesh features, but layers on significant additional functionality – in particular, the key management required to maintain the security of the mesh itself. In short, no – you can't add mesh hardware from other manufacturers."

If OpenWRT is installed on all of the access points *and* they all have radios with 802.11s support, then [OpenWRT can be used to create a unified mesh network with hardware from different vendors](https://cgomesu.com/blog/Mesh-networking-openwrt-batman/). OpenWRT is available for both the TP-Link Archer C2600 and the UniFi AP-AC-LR (but not Gen 1 hardware).